# Getting build failed as username is not readable

Tags: jenkins, github, maven-release-plugin

In my jenkins file failing at below command

Code :
         stage('Release') {
                 steps {
                    sh '/opt/maven/bin/mvn --batch-mode release:clean release:prepare release:perform'
                 }
              }
              stage('Update Rel') {
                 steps {
                    sh 'git push https://xxxx:password@github.com/dxtrsd/maven-multi-module-example.git HEAD:master'
                 }

Build failure :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M1:prepare (default-cli) on project multi: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Answer (score 1):

Following "[Bootstrap your CI with Jenkins and GitHub](https://k6.io/blog/bootstrap-your-ci-with-jenkins-and-github)" from [Michael Wanyoike](https://dev.to/brandiqa), you need to have entered your GitHub credentials first:

[image: https://k6.io/blog/static/466c3b138a22784cc325732da88aab2f/32a6f/03-github-https-credentials.webp]

Then you need to select that credential under your URL (the image shows a SSH URL, but in your case, use the HTTPS URL)

[image: https://k6.io/blog/static/bff199f732c244407edf221b3a52e16a/32a6f/06-freestyle-project-settings.webp]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue with providing user and password in developer connection url in  block in the POM.xml file

Comment: I would not recommend that option. The Jenkins Credentials System is there to securely store those credentials.